# Android Develope: How can I adjust images to the screen?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, screen, image-size

Why are the images scale despite observance of the rules for the different screen sizes.
You can see what i mean on the right side on the img.

I image sizes are [look at the image on the url].
http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3403/gn3a7t8c_png.htm

How can i fix this?

Sorry for my bad English, German and Polsih speaking are welcome, but not a must.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />
</TableRow>
```

and how it look on different screen sizes [look at the image on the url].
http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3403/2wr22nng_png.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can use `android:scaleType` attribute. to fit the image fully in the image view you can use like following

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

also this

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its still the same http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3403/qzpeusaa_png.htm